# Como pegar uma string aleatória dentre uma lista de strings?

Tags: c#, array, lista

Código:

```
nomes = new string[5];        

nomes[0] = "José";
nomes[1] = "Carlos";
nomes[2] = "João";
nomes[3] = "Miriam";
nomes[4] = "Estela";
```

Coloquei um array, mas não precisa ser com array, pode ser com lista ou alguma outra coisa que fique mais rápido.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Se a colecção onde as `strings` estiverem for acessivel por indíce pode sempre fazer:

```
var rand = new Random();
// Caso seja um array
var nextRandString = rand.Next(0, tamanhoArray -1);
// Caso seja uma lista
var nextRandString = rand.Next(0, lista.Count - 1);
```

E usar o valor aleatório para escolher a string:

```
var arrayString = new string[5];
var randString = arrayString[nextRandString];

var listString = new List<string>();
var randString = listString[nextRandString];
```

Se for uma operação que queira usar várias vezes pode sempre definir um `extension method`  que extraia o elemento aleatório (neste exemplo definido para qualquer tipo de elemento):

```
private static readonly Random _rand = new Random();

public static T GetRandomString<T>(this ICollection<T> source)
{
    var randIndice = _rand.Next(0, source.Count - 1);
    return source.ElementAt(randIndice);
}
```

Edit: Relativamente à rapidez, dado que o acesso é feito por indice a complexidade é O(1).

Answer (score 4):

### Implementação do algoritmo de embaralhamento Fisher-Yates:

Esta solução implementa o algoritmo Fisher-Yates na função `Shuffle<T>(T[] array)`, que embaralha a ordem dos ítens, de forma a você poder pegar a quantidade de resultados que necessitar, em sequência.

Postei apenas como alternativa, caso você precise de mais nomes, pois seria exagero usar a solução pra um nome só. Se a idéia é sortear apenas um nome, obviamente a solução do [@Omni](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/users/8113/) é mais adequada.

```
using System;
public class Sorteio
{
   // Esta é a função de embaralhamento que você deve implementar no seu código:
   static Random _random = new Random();

   public static void Shuffle<T>(T[] array)
   {
      var random = _random;
      for (int i = array.Length; i > 1; i--)
      {
         int j = random.Next(i);
         T tmp = array[j];
         array[j] = array[i - 1];
         array[i - 1] = tmp;
      }
   }
   // Teste do algoritmo:
   public static void Main()
   {
      string[] array = {
         "José",
         "Carlos",
         "João",
         "Miriam",
         "Estela"
      };
      // Embaralhamos a lista...
      Shuffle(array);
      foreach (string value in array)
      {
         Console.WriteLine(value);
      }      
   }
}
```

> Veja o resultado no IDEONE: http://ideone.com/FYbpDP

<sub>Implementação adaptada de http://www.dotnetperls.com/fisher-yates-shuffle</sub>